# VBA Do while Loop put data in different cells each time

Tags: vba, excel, while-loop, do-while

I have recently been given a Do While Loop to spit out some numbers, you can see in another question that I asked, My problem now is I want to put the data in cells next to where I get the data from, So I know the row number for the row I get data from but because there are 3 different possible answers that could come out. I would need to put one value in each cell for example: A3,A4,A5

Dim SNs As String

```
SNs = "Q" & xout


Const SNLength As Integer = 5

Dim SerialNumber As String
Dim index As Integer

If Left(SNs, 1) = "Q" Then SNs = Mid(SNs, 2)

index = 1



Do While index < Len(SNs)
    SerialNumber = Mid(SNs, index, SNLength)


    'Code from user


Worksheets("Calendar").Range("H" & Rng.Row).Activate

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value = "Q" + SerialNumber
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Q" + SerialNumber
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Q" + SerialNumber

    index = index + SNLength



  ' I am using the string SerialNumber and it always will have a value of 3 strings in each loop, so I need to insert them each into cells on the right, your code does what in the sense of placing them in the right cells but not the right data, the data ends up like this:
```

Q52587  Q52587  Q52587 all the same numbers when the numbers in msgbox are completely different and this is the last msgbox value.

```
Loop
```

Please can someone help me out this has got me baffled :)

Comment: what do you mean with "current" cell. The selected cell in the sheet?

Comment: @Shmukko I want to put them in the current cell next to the cell i got them from, however the code below does not work as it is only outputting one answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dim i as integer
Do While index < Len(SNs)

    SerialNumber = Mid(SNs, index, SNLength)
    MsgBox "Q" + SerialNumber
    index = index + SNLength

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value = "Q" + SerialNumber

    index = index + SNLength

    i=i+1
Loop
```

Comment: Unfortunately for some reason, this enters them correctly but keeps same value through all cells which is the last value of the do while loop, can someone else help? but thank you!

Comment: which variable are you using? please edit your question and post your full code.

Comment: ' I am using the string SerialNumber and it always will have a value of 3 strings in each loop, so I need to insert them each into cells on the right, your code does what in the sense of placing them in the right cells but not the right data, the data ends up like this: 

Q52587 Q52587 Q52587 all the same numbers when the numbers in msgbox are completely different and this is the last msgbox value.

Comment: For some reason the code keeps looping and freezes excel now

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to increment index. I changed that. You can stop Code by ctrl+pause

Comment: Thank you @shmukko you helped amazingly!